# DHCP server on internal network

Tags: server, virtualbox, dhcp

I'm trying to set up a DHCP server on an internal network with three Ubuntu VMs. 
I found out I can use VBoxManage and easily do an add dhcpserver command to set up the DHCP. So I tried that but had no success on giving IP addresses to my internal network interfaces. 
I wonder if the VBoxManage command is enough to install the DHCP server or I also need the sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server command on one of my VMs.

Answer (score 0):

I always go for installing isc-dhcp-server myself. IMHO, it doesn't hurt to give it a try and you can always snapshot/clone/template it for future uses or newer deployments. The installation is pretty straight, I give you [this link to a ShowTerm session](http://showterm.io/480c5203dd8f5b7a03ad8) showing how to do a basic install of isc-dhcp-server, just in case you need it.
For the VBoxManage part, I have used it in the past with no results, just as you say, not giving leases. (I know the whole point would be on troubleshooting it).

Comment: Thanks for the link! I went for the VBoxManage solution because I find the DHCP server configuration after a little confusing, but I'll try again with this link